# Outlook-Addin: How to retrive folder tree fast when Exchange-Online is used

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I'm using [Outlook Redemption library](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption).

I am trying to retrieve the folder list of an Outlook store. I only need folders which meet a some criterias and only need their **name** and there **DefaultMessageClass**.

Iteration the RDOFolder objects is quite slow when an Exchange Account **without** a cached is used.

So I played around with the GetAllChildFolders() and combined it the the RODFolderItems `find`method.

http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolders.htm

```cs
var allFolder = ((RDOFolder2)rootFolder).GetAllChildFolders();

string folderSelect = "SELECT Name, EntryId, DefaultMessageClass FROM  FOLDER WHERE \"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3613001F\" like '%Note%'";

try
{
RDOFolder vFolder = vFolders.Find(folderSelect);


  while (vFolder != null)
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vFolder.Name);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vFolder.EntryID);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vFolder.DefaultMessageClass);

    vFolder = vFolders.FindNext();

   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //log error here!
}
```

Now I got two questions!

**1. SQL Syntax**

**From the docmentation of `find` method**

> The properties specified in the SQL query must either use the Outlook Object Model (or RDO) 
>   property name (e.g. Subject, Email1Address)

I can't make Outlook or Redemption properties work within the SQL statement. Has somebody a working example?

**2. Performance access properties**

The online documentation states the following.

> Including the SELECT clause allows Redemption to pre-fetch the
>   properties from the folder hierarchy table without opening the item
>   resulting in a significant performance gain (see example "*I wish there was one :-)*"). If you
>   later access a property not specified in the SELECT clause, Redemption
>   will open the item.

How do I access the properties prefetch from the folder hierarchy? 
If I use RDOFolder.Name, the whole folder object is opened and there is not much of an performance gain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Which properties do not work? Are you getting a particular error?
2. What is your full SELECT statement? To avoid the chance of opening a folder, use `RDOFolders.MAPITable.ExecSQL` - it will
   return an `ADODB.Recordset` object.

Comment: This is my sql `string folderSelect = "SELECT EntryId, Name, DefaultMessageClass FROM Folder";`. 
I get the following execption:
`System.ArgumentException: Unknown property name: defaultmessageclass
   at Redemption.MAPITableClass.ExecSQL(String SQLCommand)
...`

Comment: DefaultMessageClass is not recognized because more than one MAPI property is used in RDOFolder.DefaultMessageClass - Redemption first checks if PR_DEF_POST_MSGCLASS exists. If not, it reads PR_CONTAINER_CLASS, and replaces "IPF." with "IPM."